# Find Text and Clone with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, if-statement

I have this sorta working without the `if` statement, but I'm not sure why it's not working when I used the `if` statement and with `$(this)`.

So this:

```
  if ($('.class--item:contains("Some random text items")')) 
  {
    $(this).parent().clone().appendTo($(".other--class"));
  }
```

Does **not** work. But this one does:

```
$('.class--item:contains("Some random text items")').parent().clone().appendTo($(".other--class"));
```

I'm not completely sure why one would work over the other, but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something. I'm also wondering if it's better to use one over the other as well since the `if` statement could offer some other "checking" rather than just "look for thing and clone it"

Comment: `$(this)` isn't referring to `.class--item:contains("Some random text items")` in the `if` statement. You'll need to use the actual selector.

Comment: `if ($(any_selector))` will always be true - you need to use `if ($(selector).length > 0)`

Comment: `console.log($('.class--item:contains("Some random text items")'))` would be your first step and `console.log(this, $(this))` (inside the `if`) would be your second step...

Comment: Ohhh DERP. Ok yeah...UGH. Yeah, that makes sense now. I am mentally checked out.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you are using [:contains() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) but this does not return a boolean value. Instead, you should try [jQuery.contains](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/), which does return a boolean.